# Blocking a contact with Skype4com

Tags: c#, skype, skype4com

I'm not sure how to actually block or remove a user using 'SKYPE4COMlib' extention for Visual C#. I can change my status, return messages but I do not know how to do that.
If anyone has an idea of any other useful commands please list them here also.

Comment: I'm not in a position to test it yet, but there should be a boolean IsBlocked property on the User class.

Comment: And if you want to just remove them from the buddy list without actually blocking them, you should be able to use the BuddyStatus property.

Comment: @LlamaCloud there is a check, but no actual function to block
Ill look into the buddy status

Comment: The property has both get and set defined, so I'd assume that setting it will change the status.

Comment: You mean buddie status?
It doesnt that i can see

Comment: I haven't been able to get on my Skype development computer, so maybe it doesn't (hence comments rather than answers). The reference I read showed accessors and mutators for both of those properties, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User LiamaCloud is correct.

There's a **IsBlocked** property in *User* interface.

You can do something like this:

```
ISkype skype = _skype;
var tbb = skype.Friends.Cast<User>().Where(u => u.FullName.Contains("xxx");
foreach(User notAFriend in tbb)
{
   notAFriend.IsBlocked = true;
   MessageBox.Show(friend.FullName + " " + friend.IsBlocked);
}
```

I've tested it and it works.

Best

Comment: I don't even know what issues you are facing! :) Have you tried my code? What happens?